# Function causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created the `mapWith` function like this:

```
  var mapWith=function(fn)
{
  return funtion(list)
  {
     return Array.prototype.map.call(list,function(something){
            return fn.call(this,something);
      });
  }
};
```

I use it on a function and an array:

```
 var insertLatLong=function(obj)
 {
    //inserts to db...
 }
 var inception_cities=[{lat:35.0117,lng:135.7683},
                  {lat:48.8567,lng:2.3508},
                  {lat:-4.0500,lng:39.6667},
                  {lat:33.8600,lng:151.2111},
                  {lat:34.0500,lng:118.2500}];

 var insertLocations=mapWith(insertLatLong);
 insertLocations(inception_cities);
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
ReferenceError: list is not defined
at mapWith (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/mysql.js:11:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/mysql.js:40:21)
```

Comment: There's `c` missing in your `return funtion(list)`.

Comment: the expression on my face is priceless.fixed the thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because there's `c` missing in `return funtion(list)`. Without it JavaScript thinks that you want to call something with name `funtion`. But you also want to pass `list` to it and since arguments are evaluated first then you get ReferenceError: it does not know what `list` is.